# Convert ASCII char to uint8_t C++

Tags: c++

I have a char variable AA:

```
char AA = 'E'; //0x45 HEX
```

I need to convert variable AA to the same form as the array (uint8_t), after converting I will insert it into an array:

```
uint8_t arr[] = {0x23, 0x24, 0x25, **AA**};
```

Please help with converting.

Comment: `static_cast<uint8_t>(AA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `static_cast`, ie.

```
static_cast<uint8_t>(AA)
```

Comment: you mean that `uint8_t arr[] = {0x23, 0x24, 0x25, static_cast<uint8_t>(AA)};` right?

Comment: @Andrei • Correct.  Alternatively, `auto AA = static_cat<uint8_t>('E'); //0x45 HEX`